# Convert a Spark dataframe column from string to date

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe i built from a sql context. 
I truncated the a datetime field using `DATE_FORMAT(time, 'Y/M/d HH:00:00') AS time_hourly`

Now the column type is a string. How can I convert a string dataFrame column to datetime type?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trunc(column date, format) to not to lose date datatype.
There is a to_date function to convert string to date

Comment: I tried ` trunc(column date, format)` and it works when **format is "MONTH"** BUT returns null when **format is "HOUR"** - what should I do?

Comment: can you please post sample data you are trying

Comment: I think this will work for you
myData.selectExpr("timestamp(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date_format(ts,'Y/M/d HH:00:00'),'Y/M/d HH:mm:ss')) )  as dt_formatted  ")   

Results:
======
root
 |-- dt_formatted: timestamp (nullable = true)

+--------------------+
|        dt_formatted|
+--------------------+
|2015-12-27 05:00:...|
+--------------------+

Comment: Thanks Hari! I truncated the time in the sql query as you advised.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that df is your dataframe and the column name to be cast is time_hourly
You can try the following:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType
df.select(df.time_hourly.cast(DateType()).alias('datetime'))
```

For more info please see:

1) the documentation of "cast()"
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html

2) the documentation of data-types
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/types.html